# TypeError: inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

I have concentration values stored in a different column than the uncertainty value (e.g. Ungenauigkeit As). As I have many different Elements and their uncertainty in the data frame "dataSoda", and plot each Element and the Errorplot in a subplot, I am using this for loop, which results in:
Traceback: ....in errorbar
return gca().errorbar(
TypeError: inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

[Parts of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeIOT.png)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=[10, 6])
ax = ax.flatten()
for i, column in enumerate(["As", "W", "Li", "Mn", "Sn", "Zn", "Ba"]):
    sns.scatterplot(x="A_encoded", y=column, data=dataSoda, ax=ax[i])
    plt.errorbar(x=dataSoda["A_encoded"], y=dataSoda["As"], yerr=dataSoda["Ungenauigkeit " + column], ax=ax[i])
```

I tried adding another forloop

```
for i, column in enumerate(["As", "W", "Li", "Mn", "Sn", "Zn", "Ba"]):
    sns.scatterplot(x="A_encoded", y=column, data=dataSoda, s=40, c="green", ax=ax[i], label="Soda-Pottash")

**for j, column in enumerate(["Ungenauigkeit As", "Ungenauigkeit W", "Ungenauigkeit Li", "Ungenauigkeit Mn", "Ungenauigkeit Sn", "Ungenauigkeit Zn", "Ungenauigkeit Ba"]):
     plt.errorbar(x=dataSoda["A_encoded"], y=dataSoda["As"], yerr=dataSoda[column], fmt="none", c="black",
                      capsize=4, label="Uncertainty Intervall", ax=ax[j])**
```

same error tho.

Traceback: ....in errorbar
return gca().errorbar(
TypeError: inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\", line 34, in <module>
    plt.errorbar(x=dataSoda["A_encoded"], y=dataSoda["As"], yerr=dataSoda["Ungenauigkeit " + column], fmt="none", c="black",
  File "C:\", line 2492, in errorbar
    return gca().errorbar(
TypeError: inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: Note that in Python, it is encouraged to avoid `enumerate`, and use `zip` instead.  As in `for ax_i, column in zip(ax.flatten, ["As", "W", "Li", "Mn", "Sn", "Zn", "Ba"]):` with `sns.scatterplot(..., ax=ax_i)` and `ax_i.errorbar(....)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```py
for i, column in enumerate(["As", "W", "Li", "Mn", "Sn", "Zn", "Ba"]):
    sns.scatterplot(x="A_encoded", y=column, data=dataSoda, s=40, c="green", ax=ax[i], label="Soda-Pottash")
    ax[i].errorbar(x=dataSoda["A_encoded"], y=dataSoda["As"], yerr=dataSoda["Ungenauigkeit " + column], fmt="none", c="black", capsize=4, label="Uncertainty Intervall",)
```

as the `errorbar` function of pyplot does not take `ax` as an argument, but you can use [`errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) directly from the `Axes` object.